# Save all iWork files as single files instead of packages – in batch

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to recover my data from Google Drive and have run into a problem. I use a Mac for much of work and have numerous iWork files saved to my Google Drive. However, the fact that Apple treats these files as single entities while Drive treats them as folders has become an issue.

I cannot download all my Drive data in one package, so Google provides 10 or 20 smaller zip files. But it appears that since Drive treats iWork files as folders, it thinks it's okay to break them up into multiple zips. When I then go to merge them locally I'm left with several incomplete file parts.

I would just sync everything, then copy it out of the local Backup and Sync folder, but I also have some collaborative docs in Google Docs format, and it looks like the only way to convert all of them to a readable (Microsoft Office) format is to download them from drive.google.com.

Does anybody have any ideas for this?

Comment: Have you tried the `Partial download` from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I marked this question with the google-drive-sdk (since I can't create tags), but I'm not sure I can actually take advantage of that, as the account is a Google Apps account.